# MySQL++ блокировка потока при выполнении запроса

Tags: mysql, linux

Здравствуйте.

Есть БД на выделенном сервере, к которой удаленно подключаются Linux клиенты и работают с ней через вызов хранимых процедур. Для работы с БД клиенты используют библиотеку mysql++ версии 3.2.2, подключение к сети с использованием pppoe.

Работа с БД на клиенте (подключение, вызовы хранимых процедур, обработка результатов запросов) выполняется в отдельном потоке. Код вызова хранимой процедуры (C++):

```
try {
    mysqlpp::Query sqlrequest = mConn.query();
    sqlrequest << requestS;
    sqlrequest.exec();

    return (true);
}
catch (const mysqlpp::BadQuery &e) {
    mlog << "SQL-query error[" << e.errnum() << "]: " << e.what() << mlog.endl;
    this->disconnect();
}
catch (const mysqlpp::Exception &ex) {
    mlog << "SQL-request error: " << ex.what() << mlog.endl;
    this->disconnect();
}
catch(...) {
    mlog << "Catched exception in " << __FUNCTION__ << "(): " << mlog.endl;
}
return (false);
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: если при вызове sqlrequest.exec() будет разорвано соединение с сетью, то выполнявший вызов поток на клиенте блокируется без возврата exception или кода ошибки. Время блокировки не постоянное, функция может вернуть exception через 5 минут, а может не вернуть даже через 30 (рекорд 2 часа, потом надоело ждать).

При подключении настраиваю таймауты, но в данной ситуации они ни на что не влияют.

```
mConn.set_option(new mysqlpp::ReconnectOption(true));
mConn.set_option(new mysqlpp::ReadTimeoutOption(5));
mConn.set_option(new mysqlpp::WriteTimeoutOption(5));
mConn.set_option(new mysqlpp::ConnectTimeoutOption(10));

isConnected = mConn.connect(mDatabaseName.c_str(), mDatabaseAddr.c_str(), mDatabaseUser.c_str(), mDatabasePass.c_str(), mDatabasePort);
```

Если во время блокировки потока соединение с сетью снова будет востановлено, возврат из функции все равно не происходит и поток остается блокированным.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить подобное поведение?